# Google map clustering - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Does anyone know if Flutter team is working on implementing 'built-in' google map clustering mechanism?

I currently use https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_cluster_manager which does the work but it doesn't feel the same as the Android native's one.

I am implementing a project which heavily depends on smooth clustering experience and having a proper cluster mechanism will greatly enhance the UX of the app.

Thanks,

Comment: I do not know whether they work on a built-in solution, but we use https://pub.dev/packages/fluster if you are looking for an alternative or if you want to try different solutions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Tim. I checked this as well but I prefer google_maps_cluster_manager. Looks a bit more mature.

Comment: A new "grid clusterer" is also available at: https://github.com/bdcoder2/grid_clusterer

Comment: I'm curious if you've made any progress with your project.  I've just started working with the google_maps_cluster_manager, and while it works, it's not exactly what I was hoping for.  I don't think that's a reflection on the package, just limitations of the underlying geohash concept.